# Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

Full error:

```
Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
preventDefault  @   jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3
f               @   jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js:14
b._touchMove    @   jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js:26
f               @   jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2
dispatch        @   jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3
r.handle        @   jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3
```

I'm using [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), which may be complicating the issue?  I have tried adding `cancel: false` to the draggable options, as most solutions for this error suggest.  It did not help.

This is being thrown constantly on drag, 30-80 times.

Here is all the dragging related code:

```
var t;
$(document).on('touchstart','.menu-item', function (event) {
    selectItem(this);
    var self = this;
    if ($(self).hasClass('draggable')) return;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        $(self).draggable({
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: 'clone',
            opacity: .75,
            cancel: false,
            appendTo: 'body',
            cursorAt: {
                left: 100,
                top: 100
            },
            start: function(e, ui)
            {
                $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-draggable-helper");
                $('.menu-container').addClass('stop-scrolling');
            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                $('.menu-container').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
            }
        }).draggable('enable').addClass('draggable');
        $(self).trigger(event)
    }, 800);
});

$(document).on("touchend", function () {
    clearTimeout(t);
    $('.draggable:not(.ui-draggable-helper)').draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('draggable');
});
```

Comment: For me, upgrading to jquery-3.2.1 minimized the problem. But it still shows the warning and doesn't work sometimes!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by adding an if statement in `jquery.ui.touch-punch.js`:

Here is the original code (starts at line 31):

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

  // Ignore multi-touch events
  if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
```

And here is the updated code:

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

  // Ignore multi-touch events
  if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
    return;
  }

  if(event.cancelable) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```